# Significance Testing in corpus linguistics for corpus comparison

Tags: corpora, quantitative-linguistics

I would like to compare two corpora, one consisting of Wikipedia articles and one made up of articles in printed encyclopedias. The corpus is thematically comparable because I always chose the same entry and I respected the disciplines defining subcorpora for geography, chemistry and so on.
Now I would like to compare the two subcopora (Wikipedia vs. printed encyclopedia) and the word frequencies which are in. I compared relative frequencies but I ask myself if I could apply any statistical measure to proove that my results are not random.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: So are you asking if this is a good idea? Or how / where you would get the data? You're not taking a random sample of some population, so I don't know what kind of statistical measure you're thinking of, but it would be better to ask that in a stats SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
 
Looking for suitable statistical methods is probably best asked at the Data Scinece stackexchange.

Comment: Statitically proving if your results are valid or not is not part of linguistics SE